# Get data from Scroll in http request api elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, httprequest

I'm trying to write a code in python to get all the data from an api through an http request.

I am wondering if there is a way to use the _scroll_id and it's contents in python. If so, how do I implement it or could you share some documentation regarding it?

All the documentation regarding elasticsearch in python is using a localhost...

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has a Python library that helps with pinging the database.

You can use the scan() helper function. Internally, it calls the scroll API so you don't have to worry about any of that.

For the last part of your question, you'd have to follow the tutorial to see how to connect to different databases.

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.3.3/helpers.html#scan

Comment: But does that work for https websites?

Comment: I don't get what that has to do with anything. Can you describe your usecase some more?

Way I understood it: You have a Python backend. You're querying an elasticsearch database.

What do you mean by http/https in this context?